# Removing class names from the DOM using JavaScript and Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

I want to remove multiple class names from a series of nodes in the DOM in an elegant/efficient manner. Is there a way to achieve this by using a combination of regular expressions and classList.remove()? Note I am looking for solutions in **pure JavaScript**.

**The HTML Code**

```
<div class="x">x</div>
<div class="o">o</div>
```

**My Current Method**

```
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(function(currEl) {
    currEl.classList.remove("x");
    currEl.classList.remove("o");
})
```

**My Question - the following does not work; however, is there something similar to this that exists?**

```
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(function(currEl) {
    currEl.classList.remove(/[xo]/);
});
```

Comment: `$('div.x, div.o').removeClass('x o');`

Comment: Thanks Tushar; however, I am looking for solutions in pure JavaScript - I have updated my question to emphasise this.

Comment: Or currEl.classList.remove('x', 'o');

Answer (score 0):

not exactly what you asked but this might help

```
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(function(currEl) {
    currEl.classList.remove("x","o");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add or remove multiple classes using spread syntax. You could push more classes into the array as needed...

```
let cls = ["foo", "bar"];
```

And then later:

```
currEl.classList.remove(...cls);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple selectors in querySelectorAll.

TRY this:

```
var currEl = document.querySelectorAll("div.x, div.o");
for (var i = 0; i < currEl.lenght; i++) {
    currEl[ i ].className.remove();
}
```